# How to use getContentResolver().query for Multiple selectionargs?

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I am trying to use `getContentRsolver().query()` with multiple selectionargs but not able to figure out the correct syntax. I am getting `"SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range"`

`contactNumberArray` is a string array which has all the contact numbers.

```
getContentRsolver().query(CONTENT_URI, Projection, caller_number + "=?", contactNumberArray, null);
```

This query works fine if I have only one contact number in the string array but it doesn't work if I have multiple contact numbers. Is there any specific way to query for multiple selectionargs ?

Please let me know if anyone has any pointers regarding this issue ?

Comment: What programming language? What SQLite library? What platform?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. Programming Language is Java and platform is Android Froyo 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any specific way to query for multiple selectionargs

First, your SQL syntax is wrong. You need to use the `IN` operator, not `=`, if you are expecting multiple possible values on the right-hand side of the comparison.

Second, AFAIK, you cannot use positional parameters for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `caller number in (?,?,...)` where count of `?` is your `contactNumberArray`'s length. You can also use `caller number=? OR caller number=?`.